# How can I make a query with the 3 tables, adding the total of invoices and tickets in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a query so that it returns me the total of invoices and tickets, but when using joinleft I see that they do not return all the clients. Those who do not have tickets, for example, do not return them.

```
 $clients = Client::select('clients.id','clients.name','clients.nif', \DB::raw("SUM(invoices.total) as total1, SUM(tickets.total) as total2, (SUM(invoices.total) + SUM(tickets.total)) as total"))
         ->leftJoin('invoices', function ($join1) use($invoice_year){
            $join1->on('clients.id', '=', 'invoices.client_id')
                ->whereYear('invoices.invoice_date','=', $invoice_year)
                ->groupBy('clients.id','clients.name', 'clients.nif');   
                             
         })
         ->leftJoin('tickets', function ($join2) use($invoice_year){
             $join2->on('clients.id', '=', 'tickets.client_id')
                 ->whereYear('tickets.created_at','=', $invoice_year)             
                 ->groupBy('clients.id','clients.name', 'clients.nif');
         })                        
        ->groupBy('clients.id','clients.name', 'clients.nif')
        ->having('total','>',3005)
        ->get();
```

if I do a dd, it shows this:

```
array:3 [▼  

0 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 19
    "name" => "gdfgdf"
    "nif" => "gdrfgf"
    "total1" => "40342.08"
    "total2" => "29190.40"
    "total" => "69532.48"
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 818
    "name" => "gfgf"
    "nif" => "hhfghgf"
    "total1" => "5460.62"
    "total2" => "18138.00"
    "total" => "23598.62"
  ]
  2 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 2836
    "name" => "Testing"
    "nif" => "gfhgh"
    "total1" => "3026.78"
    "total2" => "7735.00"
    "total" => "10761.78"
  ]
]
```

The ones he returns are fine, but there are more customers. I think in total the query should return about 4 or 5 customers. How can I make a query with the 3 tables, adding the total of invoices and tickets? even if there is no record of one table or another. Sorry for my english. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a full join instead of a left join.

The left join will only merge tables who has a result on all 3 tables.

The full join will merge your tables whatever the result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How to do a full join in laravel?

Comment: I don't know specifically on Laravel but instead of leftjoin just write join or fulljoin and it should do the work `->join('tableA tA', function ($join) { $join->on('field1', '=', 'field2'); }, null, null, 'FULL')`

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't work for me, it was the first thing I tried :(